# Show PHP variable in JS alert

Tags: javascript, php, html, alert

I am trying to alert message but it's not working with my string.

```
 echo "<script>alert('$lang['ALERT']');
 window.location.href ='index.php';
 </script>";
```

Not working... Help

Comment: What do you want to alert ?

Comment: string stored in $lang['ALERT']

Comment: Make sure `$lang['ALERT']` is what you expect. What **is** it alerting if anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing quotes. Keep it simple,

```
echo "<script>alert('".$lang['ALERT']."');
      window.location.href ='index.php';
      </script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

try it.

```
<script>
var alertMsg = "<?php echo $lang['ALERT'] ?>";
alert(alertMsg);
window.location.href ='index.php';
</script>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not properly quoting your variable

```
<?php
$lang['ALERT'] = 'mystring';
echo "<script>alert('".$lang['ALERT']."');window.location.href ='index.php';</script>";
?>
```

[Here's the eval](https://eval.in/385260)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<script>
    alert(<?=$lang['ALERT']; ?>);
    window.location.href ='index.php';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

quotes is the problem

```
 <?php $alert=$lang['ALERT'];?>

   <script>
    alert('<?php echo $alert?>');
    window.location.href ='index.php';
   </script>;
```